# How would I go about adding a simple menu to a Rails Application? (How to use yield :menu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add a menu to my First Ever Rails Application. Nothing too complicated. 
I've worked out that I should maybe reference it from application.html.erb, but after that I'm stuck.

Here's what I've got so far (It's not much)

```
<%= render :partial => "menu" %>
```

If I'm rendering a partial call "menu" in application.html.erb, where do I put the menu file, and what do I call it? Does it need to go in the controller of the view?

Can I call this partial from whichever layout subfolder I'm in?

Part II. If I want to show different content according to the view I'm in - how do I do this?

```
<body>
  <p>[<%= yield :menu %>]</p>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm just learning Rails, so sorry about the stupid questions. Also, I'm interested in not only a solution, but also an idea of best practices.

Comment: bjg has the correct answer, if you'd like to find more examples look for yield :sidebar implementations.

Comment: Ahh - I can see what yield :sidebar does now. I guess I wanted to know how to render partials then. I'll update the question.

Comment: Added <%= render :partial => "menu" %> to my application.html.erb file, and added _menu.erb to "views\layouts" but it's looking for the partial in the view folder for each controller. How to make it look for a parent partial?

Comment: OK - I got it. I needed to address the partial as "<p><%= render :partial => "layouts/menu" %></p>" This brings me to best practices. In which folder would a generic menu best be placed?

Comment: for this kind of content I use `app/views/shared` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In basic terms you are looking for the `content_for` helper. You put this inside your views which will then populate named blocks in partials or layouts such as `:menu`. You may elect, if you wish, to use partials to actually define the content for the `content_for` regions.

In a view:

```
<% content_for :menu do %>
  <ul>
    <li> ... </li>
    <li> ... </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

or as:

```
<% content_for :menu do %>
  <%= render :partial => "some_menu_content" %>
<% end %>
```

In the layout or partial:

```
<div id="menu">
  <%= yield :menu%>
</div>
```

Watch this [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for) from the Railscasts series for more information. It's old but still applicable